# Codeigniter: Convert code

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Im having trouble converting this code to codeigniter. Please help

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.number = table1.number
WHERE table2.number IS NULL
```

Comment: Have you looked here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data

Comment: yes, cant find instructions for IS NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2 ', 'table2.number = table1.number','left');
$this->db->where('table2.number IS NULL'); 
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
$this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');
```

example:

```
 if($this->db->query('SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.number = table1.number WHERE table2.number IS NULL') )
  {  
     echo 'success';
  }
   else
       echo 'check your query';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('table2.number IS NOT NULL', null, false)
```

> OR

```
$this->db->where(array('table2.number' IS NOT NULL));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2 ', 'table2 .user_id = table1.id','left');
$this->db->where('table1.users_id', $id); 
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$this->db->select('*')
         ->from('table1')
         ->join('table2 ', 'table2.number = table1.number','left')
         ->where('table2.users_id', NULL ); 
$query = $this->db->get();
```